Facing issue line.new in pinescript. Dont have an option to select/deselect individual lines
Below is the part of code where I am drawing DEMA lines. I want individual check-box option for all DEMA line. Currently its appearing as single option for all the DEMA lines. Please help -
dema_10 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', ta.ema(close, 10))
dema_20 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', ta.ema(close, 20))
dema_50 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', ta.ema(close, 50))
dema_100 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', ta.ema(close, 100))
dema_200 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', ta.ema(close, 200))

dema_10_line = line.new(x1 = bar_index[500], y1 = dema_10, x2 = bar_index, y2 = dema_10, extend = extend.right, color = color.olive, width = 2 )
line.delete(dema_10_line[1])

dema_20_line = line.new(x1 = bar_index[500], y1 = dema_20, x2 = bar_index, y2 = dema_20, extend = extend.right, color = color.blue, width = 2 )
line.delete(dema_20_line[1])

dema_50_line = line.new(x1 = bar_index[500], y1 = dema_50, x2 = bar_index, y2 = dema_50, extend = extend.right, color = color.black, width = 2 )
line.delete(dema_50_line[1])


dema_100_line = line.new(x1 = bar_index[500], y1 = dema_100, x2 = bar_index, y2 = dema_100, extend = extend.right, color = color.maroon, width = 2 )
line.delete(dema_100_line[1])


dema_200_line = line.new(x1 = bar_index[500], y1 = dema_200, x2 = bar_index, y2 = dema_200, extend = extend.right, color = color.red, width = 2 )
line.delete(dema_200_line[1])

enter image description here
I want individual check-box option for all DEMA line. Currently its appearing as single option for all the DEMA lines.
